# How can I dynamically change the app icon in an Expo-based Android and iOS app after installation using a dynamic URL coming from backend?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I'm developing a mobile app using Expo and I need to dynamically change the app icon after it has been installed on both Android and iOS devices. The URL for the new icon will be received from the background. I'm looking for suggestions on how to achieve this functionality within the Expo framework. Are there any specific packages or creative approaches that can help me accomplish this task? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For iOS, the alternate icon(s) must be included in the signed bundle downloaded from the App Store. You cannot use an arbitrary icon loaded from a url.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring_your_app_to_use_alternate_app_icons